# How make a div scrollable only on itself?

Tags: jquery, html, scroll

I have 5 divs:

```
<div id=A class="no"></div>
<div id=B class="no"></div>
<div id=C class="no"></div>
<div id=D class="no"></div>
<div id=E></div>
```

The page start from A and rich to E by clicking buttons. I made A,B,C,D not scrollable in that way:

```
jQuery(function($){`$(".no").on('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll MozMousePixelScroll touchmove', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();        
});
```

});

At the end E is scrollable, but at the same time I wish that when the user is on E div, he should not be allowed to scroll up to the upper divs (A,B,C,D).

Any suggestions? - http://jsfiddle.net/remat/qhcvbeeo/

Comment: can you prepare a jsfiddle, i am not sure that is clear what you`d like to achieve.

Comment: How about in your css-setting class"no" to non scrollable? :)

Comment: class .no doesn't has any style... it is just as reference for jQuery command.

Comment: you shouldnt abuse classes so you can select them with jquery... user CSS for this approach you will have to set the class of the parent element to overflow: hidden; and the "scrollable element to overflow-y: auto

Comment: @MaxBumaye I already tried your solution, but it doesn't works...

Comment: @remat maybe because you forgot to set a specific height? if you dont set a height the div doesnt know when to scroll ;)

Comment: Once again, thaks a lot for your support @MaxBumaye . I did it...

Answer (score 0):

With small change to HTML:

```
<div id="A" class="slide">
    <p>Lorem ipsum for A</p>
    <a href="#B" class="change_slide"><button type="button">Go to B</button></a>
</div>
<div id="B" class="slide">
    <p>Lorem ipsum for B</p>
    <a href="#C" class="change_slide"><button type="button">Go to C</button></a>
</div>
<div id="C" class="slide">
    <p>Lorem ipsum for C</p>
    <a href="#D" class="change_slide"><button type="button">Go to D</button></a>
</div>
<div id="D" class="slide">
    <p>Lorem ipsum for D</p>
    <a href="#E" class="change_slide"><button type="button">Go to E</button></a>
</div>
<div id="E" class="slide scrollable">
    <p>This is E div</p>
    <a href="#A" class="change_slide"><button type="button">Go to A</button></a>
</div>
```

CSS only solution would be:

```
body, html {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.slide {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.scrollable{
    overflow: auto;
    background: none #cccccc;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qhcvbeeo/1/) to test it. The issue I can see is on window resize it breaks. This can be fixed with simple Javascript:

```
function checkHash() {
    window.location.hash = window.location.hash;
};
$(window).on('resize', checkHash);
```

[Final Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qhcvbeeo/2/) <-- here.

Comment: On fiddle it works as I wish, but on my file it doesn't... Frankly I don't understand the reason why. Also I tried changing "auto" with "scroll"...
Thank you a lot for your attention.

Comment: @remat check your css selector. in your fiddle, you defined an #no element, which doesn't exist in your html. the class attribute has to be referenced as .<classname> if you use the hashtag - like in you fiddle, it tries to find an id with that name.

Comment: guys every think is in order, but still doesn't work

Comment: Could Bootstrap be in contrast with this solution?

Answer (score 0):

It would be more controllable for you and make it coexist with rest of the page, by wrapping everything within a container of fixed height. Make all `div`s with auto height, and last `div` with fixed height and `overflow:auto`.

***Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/3emyqzqt/2/embedded/result/***

```js
$("a").on("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var nextAnchor = $(this).attr('href').replace("#", ""); 
    var gotoPoint = $(".container").scrollTop() - $(".container").offset().top + $("#" + nextAnchor).offset().top
    console.log(gotoPoint);
    $('.container').animate({
        scrollTop: gotoPoint
    }, 'normal');
});
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 320px;
    width: 240px;
    margin: 8px auto;
}

.no, .yes {
    height: 100%;
}
.yes {
    overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
 <div id="div1" class="no">
  <a id="a1"></a>    
  <h2>Section A</h2>
  <p>text</p>
  <a href="#a2">Next</a>
 </div>
 <div id="div2" class="no">
  <a id="a2"></a>    
  <h2>Section B</h2>
  <p>text</p>
  <a href="#a3">Next</a>
 </div>
 <div id="div3" class="no">
  <a id="a3"></a>
  <h2>Section C</h2>
  <p>text</p>
  <a href="#a4">Next</a>
 </div>
 <div id="div4" class="no last">
  <a id="a4"></a>
  <h2>Section D</h2>
  <p>text</p>
  <a class="last" href="#a5">Next</a>
 </div>
 <div id="div5" class="yes">
  <a id="a5"></a>
  <h2>Section E</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  <a href="#a1">Top</a>
 </div>
</div>
```